# Whom is a twilio call from?

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, twilio, voip

For this call made through the API, how do I connect that with the SIP URI which I have on file with Twilio?  Whom, exactly, is this call "from"?

```
Call SID
    CA4759gfrjklg45jfgklj54klfsgjf0073a
Date
    10:55:04 UTC 2016-07-06
Start Time
    10:55:04 UTC 2016-07-06 
End Time
    10:55:19 UTC 2016-07-06 
Duration
    15 secs
Cost
    $0.015 

From
To
    (202) 456-1111 
Direction
    Outgoing API
Secure Trunking
    Disabled
Status
    Completed
```

I appreciate the recorded message that outgoing calls work, but what if they don't?  I suppose I just have to pony up the $ to fully test the outbound capability?

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed [making SIP calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls-sip) via the REST API, then the `To` parameter is the SIP URI to which you want to connect and `From` is the value used to populate the username portion of the `From` header that is passed to the SIP endpoint. This may be any alphanumeric character, as well as the plus, minus, underscore, and period characters (+-_.). No spaces or other characters are allowed.

An example to create the basic SIP dial in Java:

```
// Install the Java helper library from twilio.com/docs/java/install
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestClient;
import com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.CallFactory;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.Call;
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.CallList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class Example { 

  // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account
  public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "your_auth_token";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);

    // Build a filter for the CallList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Url", "http://www.example.com/sipdial.xml"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "sip:kate@example.com"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "Jack"));


    CallFactory callFactory = client.getAccount().getCallFactory();
    Call call = callFactory.create(params);
    System.out.println(call.getSid());
  }
}
```

Not sure exactly what trouble you're experiencing here, but I'm happy to offer more help if it's needed.